# HTTP Calls integration pattern- Making HTTP calls directly from Javascript vs Axios vs Node, which is more secure?

Tags: node.js, http, vue.js, axios

A novice javascript developer here!

A have a basic question on whats the best and secured way to make HTTP calls from a front application to a backend service that needs an authentication. My application is a SPA (using Vue.js) & getting data from Java services. Java services need authentication details and return sensitive user data.

I see there are a few options and I wanted to understand a better approach amongst all 3-

1. Making direct HTTP calls from javascript code- Concern for using this approach is, as Javascript code can also be viewed via dev tools in browser, wont it be easier for anyone to do an inspect and view all critical authentication details hence making overall integration less secure?
2. Making an HTTP call using Axios via Vue framework- Seems like Axios is Promise based HTTP client for the browser that lets you easily make HTTP calls without much code overhead. but is this secure? is Javascript code loaded in the browser? Or the front end code sends the request and axios makes the request from backend server where the application is hosted?
3. Using Node- If front end application has unique routes configured for each API call and in my application if I have a route mapping to use request module and node js backend code to make those HTTP calls, is that going to be a robust and secure way of integration?

Please let me know your thoughts and apologies if this is a dumb question!

Answer (score 0):

Not dumb at all. You're just learning.

My first question to your answer  will be: is your application server-side rendered or it's sap + backend?

If it's server-side rendered then I would say it's secured since Node will be sending pages with all required data. On the dev tool, you will only see static files being loaded.

However, if it's SAP, I am not sure whether there is a way to hide whatsoever you send to the server from the dev tool. The only one thing you will need to do is to make sure you encrypt whatever is sensitive to your application.

Comment: @tbuglc- Updated details in description. Its a SPA (frontend) + backend services in Java